# Перенос таблицы на новый лист А4

Tags: javascript, html, css

Создаю страницу А4, на эту страницу вывожу данные из базы данных в виде таблицы. Но дело в том, что данных может оказаться настолько много, что на страницу они в итоге не влезут.

Страница

```html
<div class="A4">
  Тут таблица
</div>
```

Стили

```css
.A4 {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left:60px;padding-right:60px;
    padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:60px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
 
@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  size: A4 portrait;
}
 
@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .A4 {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .noprint {
    display: none;
  }
  .enable-print {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Скрипт на создание листа при переполнении

```js
var max_pages = 100;
var page_count = 0;
 
function snipMe() {
  page_count++;
  if (page_count > max_pages) {
    return;
  }
  var long = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(this).innerHeight());
  var children = $(this).children().toArray();
  var removed = [];
  while (long > 0 && children.length > 0) {
    var child = children.pop();
    $(child).detach();
    removed.unshift(child);
    long = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(this).innerHeight());
  }
  if (removed.length > 0) {
    var a4 = $('<div class="A4"></div>');
    a4.append(removed);
    $(this).after(a4);
    snipMe.call(a4[0]);
  }
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.A4').each(function() {
    snipMe.call(this);
  });
});
```

В итоге при переполнении текстом создаётся новый лист, на котором продолжается текст.
Но если я получаю таблицу больше размера А4, то всё багается и переполненная таблица просто начинает лезть на следующий лист, на котором уже есть текст. Можно ли как-то осуществить разрыв таблицы с переносом на новый лист?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дескриптор "size: A4 portrait" должен находиться внутри правила @page

Вот пример полностью рабочего варианта:

```js
let max_pages = 100;
let page_count = 0;
let $firstPage,
  $firstTable,
  $currentTable,
  $currentPage,
  pageHeight,
  pagePaddingTop;

function checkRow() {
  let $row = $(this);
  let position = $row.position().top;
  let height = $row.outerHeight();

  if (position + height > pageHeight - pagePaddingTop) {
    if (page_count < max_pages) {
      page_count++;
      $currentPage = $('<div class="A4">').insertAfter($currentPage);
      $currentTable = $('<table>').appendTo($currentPage);
      $row.nextAll().appendTo($currentTable);
      $row.prependTo($currentTable);
      $firstTable.find('tr:first').clone().insertBefore($row);

      $currentTable.find('tr').each(checkRow);

    } else {
      $row.nextAll().remove();
      $row.remove();
    }

    return false;
  }
}

function checkElement() {
  let $el = $(this);
  let index = $el.index();
  let position = $el.position().top;
  let height = $el.outerHeight(true);

  if ($el[0].tagName !== 'TABLE') {
    if ((position + height > pageHeight - pagePaddingTop) && index > 0) {
      $currentPage = $('<div class="A4">').insertAfter($currentPage);
      $el.nextAll().appendTo($currentPage);
      $el.prependTo($currentPage);
    }
  } else {
    $firstTable = $el;
    $el.find('tr').each(checkRow);
    $el.nextAll().insertAfter($currentTable).each(checkElement);
    return false;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $firstPage = $('.A4:first');
  $currentPage = $firstPage;
  $currentTable = $firstPage.find('table')

  pageHeight = $firstPage.height();
  pagePaddingTop = parseInt($firstPage.css('padding-top')) || 0;

  $currentPage.children().each(checkElement);
});
```

```css
.A4 {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12pt;
  position: relative;
}

@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  @page {
    size: A4 portrait;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .A4 {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .noprint {
    display: none;
  }
  .enable-print {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A4">
  <p>
    Текст текст в начале 1
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>IP</th>
      <th>Supply type</th>
      <th>Old value</th>
      <th>New value</th>
      <th>Printed pages</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>08.11.2018 11:05:47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>08.11.2018 11:05:47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>08.11.2018 11:05:47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>27.09.2018 11:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>27.09.2018 11:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>27.09.2018 11:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>23.08.2018 11:05:47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>22.08.2018 15:05:12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>22.08.2018 15:05:12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>22.08.2018 15:05:12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>18.08.2018 15:06:19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>18.08.2018 15:06:19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>18.08.2018 15:06:19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>13.08.2018 09:05:15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.08.2018 10:05:28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Transfer kit</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>04.08.2018 11:05:37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>01.08.2018 11:05:23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>01.08.2018 11:05:23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>01.08.2018 11:05:23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>20.07.2018 17:05:07</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>20.07.2018 17:05:07</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>20.07.2018 17:05:07</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>20.07.2018 12:05:37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12.07.2018 18:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12.07.2018 18:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12.07.2018 18:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>01.07.2018 07:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>01.07.2018 07:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>01.07.2018 07:05:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>24.06.2018 09:05:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>24.06.2018 09:05:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>24.06.2018 09:05:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>19.06.2018 10:04:52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>18.06.2018 11:05:17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.06.2018 16:05:20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.06.2018 16:05:20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.06.2018 16:05:20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.06.2018 16:05:20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>27.01.2017 05:01:59</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>27.01.2017 05:01:59</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>27.01.2017 05:01:59</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>21.01.2017 05:05:55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>21.01.2017 05:05:55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>18.01.2017 05:02:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>17.01.2017 05:02:59</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>16.01.2017 05:03:01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>16.01.2017 05:03:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12.01.2017 05:01:12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>09.01.2017 05:04:19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>09.01.2017 05:01:51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>07.01.2017 05:01:41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>05.01.2017 05:01:44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>96</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>05.01.2017 05:01:44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>05.01.2017 05:01:44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>05.01.2017 05:01:44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30.12.2016 05:01:45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>29.12.2016 05:02:24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuser kit</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>28.12.2016 05:01:27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>26.12.2016 05:02:06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>25.12.2016 05:01:48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>25.12.2016 05:01:39</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>24.12.2016 05:01:56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>22.12.2016 05:02:10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>19.12.2016 05:01:34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>15.12.2016 05:05:55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>15.12.2016 05:05:55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>14.12.2016 05:03:15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12.12.2016 05:00:53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10.12.2016 05:01:32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>04.12.2016 05:01:20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>04.12.2016 05:01:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>04.12.2016 05:01:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>04.12.2016 05:01:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>03.12.2016 05:00:35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>30.11.2016 05:00:40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>25.11.2016 05:02:14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>25.11.2016 05:02:14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>22.11.2016 05:01:16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>19.11.2016 15:40:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>19.11.2016 15:39:43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>19.11.2016 05:00:43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>19.11.2016 05:00:34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>18.11.2016 05:00:45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>17.11.2016 05:02:26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Transfer kit</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>16.11.2016 05:02:18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>16.11.2016 05:02:18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12.11.2016 05:01:45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12.11.2016 05:01:37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>11.11.2016 05:00:42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>11.11.2016 05:00:23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Yellow cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>08.11.2016 05:00:43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cyan cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>08.11.2016 05:00:43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>08.11.2016 05:00:42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Magenta cartridge</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>08.11.2016 05:00:42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Black cartridge</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>99</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>07.11.2016 05:03:31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>LASERJET 5550 SERIES</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Transfer kit</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>07.11.2016 05:00:28</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    Текст текст в конце 1
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
  <p>
    Текст текст текст
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Теперь как-то получается, что вот допустим таблица становится больше А4, но под ней ещё есть другой текст. В итоге часть таблицы на первом листе, под ней текст (который причём выходит за лист и вообще под второй лист) и на втором листе продолжение этой таблицы. И можно ещё как-то при переходе на страницу дублировать заголовки таблицы? А то ширина столбцов изменяется из-за этого.

Comment: Вот решение с дублированием заголовков (одна строка в скрипте) https://jsfiddle.net/frozencoast/95ng0y7e/3/. А насчет текста под таблицей - добавь пожалуйста пример HTML, а то тяжеловато ориентироваться

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ocjxugf/ Вот получается. В HTML файле текст после таблицы, но на странице он после 1го листа таблицы.

Comment: Вот вариант для такого случая - https://jsfiddle.net/frozencoast/ykmcxpge/9/. Примечание: текст после таблицы должен быть в тегах

Comment: Теперь появился косяк, что если есть ещё и текст перед таблицей) https://jsfiddle.net/qsbg3c97/ На первых листах идёт начало таблицы, на последнем листе текст, который был перед таблицей, конец таблицы и текст который после неё.

Comment: Мда, условия постоянно меняются) ну если подводных камней больше не будет - то вот держи https://jsfiddle.net/frozencoast/29k6whm1/1/